# how to address the security concern of having an NSException format use a non-string literal

Tags: iphone, objective-c, error-handling, compiler-errors, nserror

I'm using [mailcore2](https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2) which is all block based. Typically they define an operation like so

```
SomeMailCoreOp *op = [session getOp];
[op start:^(NSError* error, id result) {
    if (error) {
        // handle error code            
    }    
}];
```

So what I wanted to do is basically simply throw an `NSException` every time an error is encountered.. so that I can catch it somewhere else in my code base.. So I created a category for `NSError`:

```
@implementation NSError (Addons)

-(NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",
            [self localizedDescription], [self localizedFailureReason]];        
}
@end
```

and this is how I would like to typically handle errors:

```
SomeMailCoreOp *op = [session getOp];
[op start:^(NSError* error, id result) {
    if (error) {
        [NSException raise:@"failure" format:[error description]];            
    }    
}];
```

I thought this makes sense since in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSException_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSException/raise%3aformat%3a) for NSException they got this for `format`:

> format,    A human-readable message string (that is, the exception
>   reason) with conversion specifications for the variable arguments that
>   follow.

yet I always get this compiler warning when I do the above:

```
format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure)
```

how do I get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`format` is a format string, like in `NSLog()` or `[NSString stringWithFormat:]`. In your case

```
[NSException raise:@"failure" format:@"%@", [error description]];
```

will not produce the warning. Have a look at the [Apple Docs for formatting string objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html) for more information.

For more information why having a non-literal string as the format is insecure, see [Uncontrolled format string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format_string_vulnerabilities) on Wikipedia

Note that Apple discourages the use of Exceptions for flow-control:

From [Cocoa Core Competencies](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ExceptionHandling.html):

> Although exceptions are commonly used in many programming environments to control programming flow or to signify errors, do not use exceptions in this way in Cocoa and Cocoa Touch applications. Instead, you should use the return value of a method or function to indicate that an error has occurred, and provide information about the problem in an error object.

From [Dealing with Error](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH9-SW1):

> If you’re coming from other platforms and languages, you may be used to working with exceptions for the majority of error handling. When you’re writing code with Objective-C, exceptions are used solely for programmer errors, like out-of-bounds array access or invalid method arguments. These are the problems that you should find and fix during testing before you ship your app.